# Forever exclude, ignore files in existing repo using git

Tags: php, git, apache, ignore

I'm working with a large PHP project in git and having trouble with my working copy because of a couple files, including the .htaccess, .gitignore and database configuration files getting overwritten or wanting to be staged/committed.

The problem I'm running into is that every time I try to switch branches, I'm bothered to either stash my changes or told that I can't merge because files are not uptodate. I've tried updating my exclude to the following:

```
.htaccess
.gitignore
./application/config/vagrant/config.php
./application/config/vagrant/database.php
```

Along with this, I've also tried to set these files to assume-unchanged - which is where i get the issues trying to switch branches and it telling me the files are not uptodate.

What I'd *like* to happen is for those files to be completely ignored forever. Whenever I switch branches, I don't want them to be merged, I just want them to essentially be removed from the repo without affecting any of the other users that work on the project.

Comment: It sounds like those files are currently tracked by Git. You need to stop tracking them; then, you'll be able to ignore them.

Comment: This command, then? `git rm --cached`

Comment: Yes. Apply `git rm --cached` to all the files that are currently tracked but that you want to ignore.

Comment: Thanks! If you want to submit this as an answer, I'll accept it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description of the problem, it seems that the offending files

```
.htaccess
.gitignore
./application/config/vagrant/config.php
./application/config/vagrant/database.php
```

are already being tracked; perhaps you or one of your collaborators started tracking them by mistake a long time ago...

If you want Git to be able to ignore those files, you first need to tell Git to stop tracking them by running

```
git rm --cached <paths>
```

Then, and after adding appropriate entries in your `.gitignore` file, you'll be able to ignore those files, as desired.